# Can I hide selected area/iteration nodes in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

In order to make sure that obsolete versions of the product aren't selected for a work item's iteration, I would like to be able to cloak certain iteration nodes from view, when opening a new work item.

For example, if the current production version of my site is 3.5, and 3.6 and 4.0 are in development, I want to make sure that when a user creates a new work item, versions that are older than 3.5 (e.g. 3.4, 2.7) will **not** be selectable.

I can conceive of a way to do this creating a custom control, but I'd like to avoid those, as they'd require development of both desktop and web controls, and would have to be deployed to all users.

Any ideas, directions, or just an "it can't be done", would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Assaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can hide it as a selection.

However you can set the security for "Edit work items in this node" to deny and they will not be able to save workitems with the area or iteration selected.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm hoping I can find a way to visually prune the tree once it gets unwieldy.

Comment: Even though everybody else said that it can't be done, in the end, denying the ability to edit work items is the next best thing, so I'm marking this as the answer. Thanks, Assaf.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 90% sure it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself:

Along the line of access control, I believe if you deny "View this node" permission on a user then she will not be able to see this node at all. Be aware that she will probably not be able to see the work items that are under this node, but I guess you are fine with that.

Another thing to note is that this solution might not work with Administrators (because if all Administrators are denied view permission and cannot see the area path then it's lost forever).

Comment: I thought that denying "View this node" cloaks the node from the user as well.

Unfortunately, it turns out that this feature only denies the ability to view the security settings for this node. This is explained in  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx

Any other ideas how to solve this? I know I can deny the ability to save work items that are under an iteration node, but I'm hoping to hide obsolete nodes as well as denying their usage.